# php regex match url contains and replace slash with dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Change only url which contains change.com replace "/" with "-" and put .html at end

```
<a href="http://www.notchange.com/adf/i18n/wiki/" class="coasfs" >as3rc</a>

<a href="http://www.change.com/q/photoshopbattles/comnts/2n4jtb/psbattle_asgfdhj/" class="coasfs" >as3rc</a>

<a href="http://www.change.com/q/photottles/commes/" class="coefs" >ase3rc</a>
```

i need result link bellow

```
http://www.change.com/q-photoshopbattles-comments-2n4jtb-psbattle_asgfdhj.html
```

please help  me i tried many time with regex but failed.

Comment: here i create some http://regex101.com/r/dZ1sE3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this, but it uses Regexes in conjunction to PHP functions. This method will be simpler than a pure Regex solution.

```
$string = '<a href="http://www.notchange.com/adf/i18n/wiki/" class="coasfs" >as3rc</a>'
    . '<a href="http://www.change.com/q/photoshopbattles/comnts/2n4jtb/psbattle_asgfdhj/" class="coasfs" >as3rc</a>'
    . '<a href="http://www.change.com/q/photottles/commes/" class="coefs" >ase3rc</a>';

//The regex used to match the URLs
$pattern = '/href="(http:\/\/www.change.com\/)([^">]*)"/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    //trim the ending slash if exists, replace the slashes in the URL path width a -, and add the .html
    $newUrl = $val[1] . str_replace("/", "-", trim($val[2], "/")) . '.html';

    $string = str_replace($val[0], 'href="' . $newUrl . '"', $string);
}
echo $string;
```

I used the regex to help find the urls that need to be modified, then use some built-in functions that PHP has to finish the job.

Comment: Why do you replace the underscore?

Comment: not working i think it works with preg_replace i just need to replace / with - /q/photoshopbattles/comnts/2n4jtb/psbattle_asgfdhj/

Comment: @uyrxe: Yea, I apologize. I misread what you were wanting. I've updated the answer to what you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks.. i want to echo full $string with changed url not only urls

Comment: very very thanks i definitely earn $1100 per month by your help after one month